# Visual Studio 2013 extension to have a "floating WPF container"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

As the title says, I'm trying to understand if there's a way to build a VS packaged extension that simply creates a WPF canvas in which I can put WPF elements at IDE level.

I found the way to manage the adornment layer in the editor windows, but it only shows contents inside (yep) the editor windows, and it responds to the zoom level (and I would like to avoid it).

Then I see I can simply create a toolwindow and put components in there, but then I cannot "hide" the toolwindow frame itself.

As I can see there's no way to create a custom empty container in the IDE, am I right?

Comment: You can just create a System.Windows.Window with WindowStyle=None.

Comment: But how? The toolwindow doesn't expose the WindowStyle property.

Comment: Not a toolwindow, create just a regular WPF window.

Comment: But what is the top level element on which I can append a new WPF window? Can't find an example on how to do this...